# Rollback or DiscardChanges with Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework

Is there a way to rollback the changes within a context in Entity Framework 4.3.1.0? If not, what is the standard way to implement transactional behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework is transactional by its nature. Changes are only committed on a call to SaveChanges. There is no explicit roll-back operation, however you can simply dispose your context and all changes will not be applied.